# Python - google-trans-new throwing error on code that was working

Tags: python, google-translate, google-translation-api

I've been using a Google Translate API to translate automatically a couple of words, this has been working fine for a couple of months but 2-3 days ago I've started to getting problems because this snippet was raising an error.

**Code**:

```
from google_trans_new import google_translator

translator = google_translator()
print(status) #light rain 
translate_text = translator.translate(status, lang_tgt='pt')
print(translate_text) #chuva leve
```

**Error**

```
File "bot.py", line 74, in checkBadConditions
    translate_text = translator.translate(status, lang_tgt='pt')
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google_trans_new/google_trans_new.py", line 188, in translate
    raise e
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google_trans_new/google_trans_new.py", line 152, in translate
    response = json.loads(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 358 (char 357)
```

I've also tried to `translate_text = translator.translate(status, lang_src='en', lang_tgt='pt')` and it didn't work either

Was there any update? What am I doing wrong

Comment: Is there any way that the status you're giving has a different format from before ? It does seem that the input data isn't looking as expected

Comment: status isn't the problem because I've switch status to `"Hello"` and the error presisted

Comment: I tried on my machine and have the same error. From the [official github](https://github.com/lushan88a/google_trans_new), we can see they added a bugfix 6 days ago. Was it working like 4 days ago or may the bugfix be the reason why this error appeared ? 

Also check [this issue](https://github.com/lushan88a/google_trans_new/issues/36) from 10 days ago that seems to be very related to your error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be an error from the package `google-trans-new` that is known and already corriged. (Check [this](https://github.com/lushan88a/google_trans_new/issues/36) discussion for more information).

A new version of the module with the bugfix hasn't been released to pip yet. So you have to manually do the modification or wait for the newt version to be released.

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.formatter import HTMLFormatter
from googletrans import Translator
import requests

translator = Translator()

class UnsortedAttributes(HTMLFormatter):
    def attributes(self, tag):
        for k, v in tag.attrs.items():
            yield k, v
```

Check this 2 alternatives for Python transtator code:

https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/python-code-text-google-translate-website-translation-beautifulsoup-library.html

or here:

https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/example-google-translate-api-key-python-code-beautifulsoup.html